# Javascript - how to pars json into two lists

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to work with chaert.js and I am using ajax to get the json data.
My Json file looks like this:

```json
[
    {
        "timestamp": "00:00:00.000000",
        "true_count": 0
    },
    {
        "timestamp": "01:00:00.000000",
        "true_count": 0
    },
    {
        ...
    }
]
```

I need to get time stamp into my _label variable and i need to get true_count into my _data variable.
Here is what i tried so far:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var _data =[];
   var _labels = [];
   $.ajax({
   url: "chart_data",
   type: "get",
   success: function(response) {
     full_data = JSON.parse(response);
    full_data.forEach(function(key,index){
        _data = key.true_count;
        _labels= key.timestamp;
        
    });
     //_data = [full_data['true_count']];
     //_labels = [full_data['timestamp']];
   },

 });
});
```

I am not getting any error but my chart is not showing the data. I am very certain that i am not parsing the data properly. Can you please tell me what am i doing wrong?

As i mentioned, i just need _data to store all true_count and _labels to store all timestamps.

Thank you

So here is the full version of my code with the updates you suggested. For some reason my chart is not showing the data, it actually seems that is only showing the first record which is 00:00:000 with 0 true_count.

```
 /* chart.js chart examples */

$(document).ready(function(){
   var _data =[];
   var _labels = [];
  $.ajax({
   url: "chart_data",
   type: "get",
   success: function(response) {
     full_data = JSON.parse(response);
     full_data.forEach(function(key,index) {
     _data.push(key.true_count);
     _labels.push(key.timestamp);    
 });
     //_data = [full_data['true_count']];
     //_labels = [full_data['timestamp']];
   },

 });

// chart colors
var colors = ['#007bff','#28a745','#333333','#c3e6cb','#dc3545','#6c757d'];

/* large line chart */
var chLine = document.getElementById("chLine");
var chartData = {
  labels:_labels,
  datasets: [
  {
    data:_data,
    backgroundColor: [
                          'rgba(42, 157, 244, 0.1)'
                      ],
                      borderColor: [
                          'rgba(42, 157, 244, 1)',
                          'rgba(33, 145, 81, 0.2)',
                      ],
                      borderWidth: 1
  }]
};

if (chLine) {
  new Chart(chLine, {
  type: 'line',
  data: chartData,
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: false
        }
      }]
    },
    legend: {
      display: false
    }
  }
  });
}
;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually almost there. The problem is that your current version just reassigns the variables:

```
full_data.forEach(function(key,index) {
    _data = key.true_count;
    _labels= key.timestamp;    
});
```

The result is that you end up with the last value only, since you're constantly replacing the previous value. What you want to achieve is *add* each element to your lists:

```
full_data.forEach(function(key,index) {
    _data.push(key.true_count);
    _labels.push(key.timestamp);    
});
```

Comment: thank you for quick response. I did adjustment as you suggested and i think is working however my chart is showing only first record.

Comment: You will need to move the creation of your chart to inside the success handler. Everything that is in the "success" function will be executed once the data has arrived. Right now you create the chart immediately, which might mean your request is still in progress.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. Your suggestions worked :-)